# jQuery Grid with autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am building a webapp using jQuery and jQuery UI.  I am at an impass.  What I need is a jQuery grid that has editable fields and somehow incorporate an autocomplete field on one of these editable cells and i cant seem to find any grid offerings that implement this.

I've been looking at **StickGrid** and **jgGrid**

I especially like jqGrid since it is Themeroller ready.  Does any one know if anyone has sucessfully been able to integrate an autocomplete on one of these grids, or any other jquery grid for that matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want should be achievable pretty easy. I made you a quick copy-paste/steal-together demopage.

If you click the Date column you get a calendar selector.

If you click the Client column and delete the content you will see an autocompleter (css doesn't fit quickpastewhatever) which lists american cities (i know cities aren't client names just a demo).

Code taken from [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php) Cell Editing demo page + [jQuery Autocomplete](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) demo page

http://jsbin.com/owatu (append `/edit` to the url to see the code)

Of course the demo is a bit rough around the edges

- css problems
- quick hack in afterSaveCell inserted to get jQgrid to insert the selected value from the autocompleter if user uses arrowkeys+enter key with mouse it works without hack

I guess the afterSaveCell hack could be removed when cleanly integrating autocomplete and jqGrid with each other.

Basically it boils down to

```
jQuery("#celltbl").jqGrid({
    ...
    {name:'name', width:100, editable:true}, //e.g.
    ...
    afterEditCell: function (id,name,val,iRow,iCol) {
        if(name=='name') {
            //cities here is local json object
            jQuery("#"+iRow+"_name","#celltbl").autocomplete(cities);
        }
    },
    afterSaveCell : function(rowid,name,val,iRow,iCol) {
        if(name == 'name') {
            jQuery("#celltbl").jqGrid('setRowData',rowid,{name:jQuery(".ac_over").text()});
            jQuery(".ac_results").remove();
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I was actually looking out for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I have not implemented autocomplete, but I have worked with jqGrid and it has an awesome support for javascript events.

For example:
If you put an id in one of the cells and want to auto populate info in other cells u can use 
afterEditCell where u specify a custom function which will receive rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol and check if the iRow is the same row as your id, take that value and populate other cells based on that value. - basically auto complete

Or can use beforeEditCell event and create your own function which will receive rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol and return result will be placed in the cell.

check out events section
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing

good luck!

Comment: That's interesting and will come in handy if I end up using jqGrid but I think I didn't make myself totally clear.  What I'm looking for is more like a dropdown coming off the editable cell populated with items that start with the text that has been typed up to that moment, and the user can click one of the items in the dropdown and so the field would autocomplete.  Haven't had time to look at the code but could something like that be adapted into jqGrid?

Comment: i think its doable, u would need to attach a jquery onkeyup event to the cell object which calls a webservice on each key press. The challenge would be how to get that object from the beforeEditCell, cus it only sends rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol... some clever jquery would be needed